# "Uncaught [object Object]" when throw and catch

Tags: javascript, error-handling, exception

I have a little JS problem, when I throw an exception in a $.getJSON, this exception is not catched by the parent function and I have a JS error ..

Chrome's console returns me that :

```
Uncaught [object Object]
(anonymous function) @ ConfLoader.class.js:24
j                    @ jquery.min.js:2
k.fireWith           @ jquery.min.js:2
x                    @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
```

I have many other throw and try/catch and I have not this problem .. 
Can you explain me why ?

Here is my ConfLoader "class" :

```
var ConfLoader = {
    /* Attributes */
    apiToken : null,
    lavaBaseURL : null,
    apiURL : null,

    /* Init method */
    load : function(file) {
        $.getJSON(file, function(data) {
            if (data.apiToken)
                this.apiToken = data.apiToken;
            else
                throw new Exception("Token API (apiToken) not found into config file.");
            if (data.lavaBaseURL)
                this.lavaBaseURL = data.lavaBaseURL;
            else
                throw new Exception("Lava URL (lavaBaseURL) not found into config file.");
            if (data.apiURL)
                this.apiURL = data.apiURL;
            else
                throw new Exception("API URL (apiURL) not found into config file.");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            throw new Exception("File '"+file+"' not found.");
        });
    },

    /* Methods */
    getApiToken : function () {
        return this.apiToken;
    },
    getLavaBaseURL : function () {
        return this.lavaBaseURL;
    },
    getApiURL : function () {
        return this.apiURL;
    }
}
```

And the line "throw new Exception("File '"+file+"' not found.");" throw me a JS error .. But I catch this exception here when I cann ConfLoader's method "load" :

```
var Powers = {
    /* Attributes */
    confLoader : null,

    /* Methods */
    init : function(configFile) {
        try {
            this.confLoader = ConfLoader.load(configFile);
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    },
    launch : function() {
        try {

        } catch (e) {

        }
    }
}
```

"Exception" class is a custom Exception class which works for other throw :

```
function Exception(msg, fatal) {
    this.message = msg;
    this.fatal = fatal;

    this.isFatal = function() {
        return this.fatal;
    }
    this.getMessage = function() {
        return this.message;
    }
    return this;
}
```

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fail` handler of `$.getJSON` is asynchronous, meaning that exceptions thrown in it will not be propagated up to the caller of `$.getJSON`. Instead of throwing an exception, try handling the failure in the `fail` handler instead.

(You'll also find your success handler has the same problem.)

Comment: Oh yes, I suspected that .. But, how to solve it ? with a $.ajax with a "async: false" ? .. This is not really clean ..

Comment: @JorisBertomeu Like I said, handle the failure in the event handler, either directly or by calling another function that handles failures.

Comment: Ok, fine ! May I use promises maybe ?

Comment: @JorisBertomeu Yes, you could also use a promise to handle success or failure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Could you show me really quickly how to implement it ? ..